# AppEngine 'explicitly cancelled' error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, scheduled-tasks, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Google AppEngine and the deferred library, with the `Mapper` class, as described [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred.html) (with some improvements as in [here](http://www.arikfr.com/blog/app-engine-mapping-entities-using-deferred-tasks.html)). In some iterations of the mapper I get the following error:

```
CancelledError: The API call datastore_v3.Put() was explicitly cancelled.
```

The Mapper usually runs fine, I used to have a higher batch size, so that it would actually hit the `DeadlineExceededError`, and that was handled correctly.

Just to be sure, I reduced the batch_size to a very low number, so that it never even hits the `DeadlineExceededError` but I still get the `CancelledError`.

The stack trace is as follows:

```
File "utils.py", line 114, in _continue
  self._batch_write()
File "utils.py", line 76, in _batch_write
  db.put(self.to_put)
File "/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1238, in put
  keys = datastore.Put(entities, rpc=rpc)
File "/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 255, in Put
  'datastore_v3', 'Put', req, datastore_pb.PutResponse(), rpc)
File "/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 177, in _MakeSyncCall
  rpc.check_success()
File "/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 474, in check_success
  self.__rpc.CheckSuccess()
File "/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 126, in CheckSuccess
  raise self.exception
CancelledError: The API call datastore_v3.Put() was explicitly cancelled.
```

I can't really find a lot of information about this 'explicity cancelled' error, so I was wondering what caused it and how to investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a `DeadlineExceededError`, you are allowed a short amount of grace time to handle the exception, eg defer the remainder of the computation.

If you run out of grace time the `CancelledError` kicks in.

There should be no way to catch/handle the `CancelledError`

Comment: I suspected that. However, the `Mapper` class was designed to handle these kinds of things. It even has a default batch size of 200. Which things influence the time it takes for `db.put()` to finish/return? I assumed it was only the batch size, so using smaller batches (only 4 !) would make put finish faster and avoid the `CancelledError`. Are there other things that make `db.put()` take longer that I could optimize?? (More indexes? ListProperties? ReferenceProperties?)

Comment: Any idea , "how can we avoid this?"

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is still correct. I'm seeing these exceptions being raised in Taskqueues (which have a 10 minute time limit) at about 54 seconds into the request.